# Blank page after including file - IntelliSMS

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, include-path

I have problem:
It is really strange for me as when I add:

```
include ("/home/p002/htdocs/Project2/library/IntelliSMS/SendScripts/IntelliSMS.php");
```

And it is correct path I have only blank page! But when I add:

```
include ("/homedddd/p002/htdocs/Project2/library/IntelliSMS/SendScripts/IntelliSMS.php");
```

And it is wrong path the page is not blank, it looks like working OK but of course it can not find this file. It means something is wrong with this IntelliSMS library it does not work with my server but I do not know why? Probably server blocking sending sms or something? Do you have any idea? This library is from http://intellisms.co.uk/sms-gateway/php-sdk/ Maybe there is problem that it needs the OpenSSL extension module? What should I do it to start works?

Comment: Does the included PHP script actually output anything? If not, a blank page is to be expected.

Comment: No it does not return nothing it take data and send it by the internet and do not echo nothing

Comment: So, what kind of output are you expecting?  It sounds to me like everything is fine. You include the library, and your script ends.  No output ever happens, because neither your code nor the library's code outputs anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You verrry much for all your help but I have found solution!

There was problem that there was an unexpected char on the beginning of this IntelliSMS.php probably /r/n and the server was debian so I have delete all chars on the beginning of the script and add once again an enter and it started works!

I have lost so many time just for it :/ Life is brutal!
I hate this invisible errors! ;)

Thanks!